# How to move sort arrow in jquery dataTable

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

Is there any way to put sorting arrows near the name of the column? Now I got this[image]

And I need to be like this

[image]

And I can't narrow the column, because column need to be wide to display info in it.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not do that because that sorting image is background-image of the . You can set the position of background-image left/center/right . But you can't set the position just after text ends.

[image]

One Idea I can give that , You manually add some html and style it according to the events.

Good Luck.

Comment: With themeroller i think  you have more control over it: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html

Comment: Yes. I appreciate. But then extra html are needed. Need some css modification too

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `display: inline;` css property for that particular th